# change Gnome Terminal background color when focused/unfocused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, colors, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 18 and I was trying to have the background color of my Gnome Terminal changed on the fly when it gets/lost focus (BTW: I do not use Tabs - just one single tab per Terminal) so that I can easily identify the one currently focused
Is this something that can be configured in 
`~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GTK 3.22, all elements in unfocused windows have the `:backdrop` pseudoclass.

(See this [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) of all supported CSS syntax.)